# How can i embed php code in JQuery append

Tags: jquery

The bolded line format is not correct...
Anyone, please help me to solve this problem

`$abc += '<div class="icon">'`

`$abc += '<i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>';`

**`var php = '<?php echo DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML("4445", "C39") ?>';`**

`$abc += php;`

`$abc += '</div>';`

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

you can not.

### Long answer

You need to understand that PHP code is **backend** code and will only get executed by the server. While javascript code is **frotend** code and will only get executed by the browser.

A browser can not execute server code directly but ti can communicate with the server via HTTP requests.

I would recommend reading up on [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: So please tell me how can I append bar code in HTML ??

Comment: You can **not** again read up on ajax and how to have the frontend communicating with the backend


eidt: I suppose you could use a frontend library that creates barcodes for you.